# In struts.xml <package name="" extends=" , ,"> can Inherit from more than one package?

Tags: java, struts2

Below is mycode:

```
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default,hibernate-default,...">
   ---
   </package>
```

Here, is there any limitation of inheriting package or we can inherit any number of packages.

Comment: Package can extend more than one package.

Comment: For more details, the parsing of the _extends_ attribute in XML can be found in the source : https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/struts-2-5-x/core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/providers/XmlConfigurationProvider.java#L660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit for inheriting package, you can inherit any number of packages.

> The extends attribute is optional and allows one package to inherit
>   the configuration of one or more previous packages - including all
>   interceptor, interceptor-stack, and action configurations.

Comment: Adding link for reference : https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/package-configuration.html